# IBM MobileFirst Platform 6.3 Trail Issue

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I Worked on IBM MobileFirst Platform App. is it 30 days trial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no expiration date on the Developer Edition. It is free for all time.

The only restriction is that you may not use it to deploy applications to production environments - for this you must purchase a license from IBm.

Comment: if user clicks a link in a browser or if he enters mobile no .. then app will automatically download to respective mobile device.. how can i achive this

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about; you are writing completely out of context in case you haven't noticed.

Comment: I Done Hybrid application using IBM Worklight.I created apk file using eclipse and installed in android device.if my Mobile first Server is Stopped my app in android not working.. if my Mobile first Server is Started then My app working .. can u tell me what is happing?

Comment: Your application is trying to connect to the server... if you stop the server, it will fail connecting to the server, thus fail to work. Please read the tutorials @ http://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform

Comment: In my app iam connecting to My Database were that database up and running why should Mobile First Server should sarted?

Comment: Adapters go through the server. The server must be available.

Comment: is any another way to do My App should work even if  server is turned off.

Comment: without adapters how can i connect to database

Comment: using ajax. please google.

Comment: but note that if you require security and are using worklight authentication with your adapters, you will not be able to do this with ajax.

Comment: you may want to read about Offline Authentication: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/offline-authentication/

Comment: so other people apps are also done using adapters?

Comment: With worklight, you use adapters.

Comment: ok. so if i want use IBM Worklight I want to use adapters.. so I want to Move My Mobile First Server to Production were it always up and running.. is der any document for Development to Production Configuration

Comment: go read: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNJXP/welcome.html