# IBM Worklight Mobile First Server

Tags: server, mobilefirst-server

I Done Hybrid application using IBM Worklight.I created apk file using eclipse and installed in android device.if my Mobile first Server is Stopped my app in android Mobile not working. if my Mobile first Server is Started then My app working can u tell me what is happing?

Comment: Why do you think the app would work if you turn the server off?

Comment: My Mobile First Server is off and i opened app in android.. app is to update the entered user password.. when i clicked on update its showing Checking User Loading Message upto 1 Min.. Then I started My Server.. I done Same thing within 5 sec it stated that password is updated sucessfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application must connect to the Server.
If you close the server, it will fail connecting to the server.

If you start the Server, it will then succeed to connect to the Server.

If you want your application to continue functioning to some degree while the server is not reachable, you may want to see if [Offline Authentication](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/offline-authentication/) is what you're looking for.

From your [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476268/ibm-worklight-6-3-trail-issue/28476595?noredirect=1#comment45306933_28476595), it also seems that you're trying to use MFP adapters while the server is offline; this will not work. adapters use the server. Review my comments in the other question.